# Facebook "Reviews" Tab Data -- Where is it stored in Graph API and how to access it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

I'm totally stumped here. I'm trying to get access to the data that appears under the reviews tab in the Facebook Page http://facebook.com/freemanfoxx (Page ID=149530265092626).

I've figured out that all data in a Facebook profile can be retrieved as JSON using the Graph API but I'm totally stumped about the data populated on the "Reviews" tab. It appears to be it's own Application separate from the Facebook core and this is probably why I'm lost.

Any leads/tips/experts out there? Here are some of the links I've been searching for Help.

developers.facebook.com/docs/api 
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ 
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

My overall goal is to take this data into Yahoo! Pipes and then combine it with data from a Google Form to create an RSS feed to be output to a webpage I'm building.

Your thoughts and help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your reviews tab on the facebook page is: 
http://www.facebook.com/easyinspection?sk=app_6261817190.

6261817190 is the application id (not page id), and that is what you will be using next.
You can get all reviews by a request to:

http://graph.facebook.com/6261817190/reviews. If you do not want to go page by page, retrieving 25 reviews at a time (take a look at next page url), you can get it all in a single request, like this:

http://graph.facebook.com/6261817190/reviews?limit=100000000&offset=0

Comment: Documentation can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/
Please keep in mind that facebook has a data size limit. Also requests which take too long in evaluation will return empty datasets instead all requested data. A limit=100000000&offset=0 parameter will possibly stop working suddenly, in case facebooks api decides it is too complicated to fulfill the request.

Comment: hello Daniel can you please tell me where can i get the application id ?

Comment: If I have to get the reviews from a facebook page (I am not the owner of that page) then how will I get the app id ? I am unable to understand.

Comment: same here, how do you get the app id?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for this data. Your only chance will be a web page crawl ov your reviews and grab the content from there.

Comment: and @Ryan, Please have a look at the answer from Danial Hursan

Comment: Well, now there is an API method ... see Daniels Answer and comments.