# How do I access my facebook page's reviews from the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-page, review

I have been trying to pull the reviews left on my facebook page.

I tried following the advice given from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541368/facebook-reviews-tab-data-where-is-it-stored-in-graph-api-and-how-to-access).

However, when I try this, I only get the reviews left specifically for the application and not the reviews left on my page.

I also tried pulling the reviews from the, /136789689670650/tabs/reviews connection of my page.  This only pulled up the information on the tab and not the reviews the tab contains.

So does anyone know how I can use the Graph to obtain the reviews of my page?
Thank you.
--christopher

Answer (score 3):

[edit] sorry, I see you're asking about when you install the reviews tab on a regular page , not an app page - this is not currently exposed via the API [/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to look into this page
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/