# Get App_id from facebook page with rating app - app_id is 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to collect users' ratings for this page:
https://www.facebook.com/UniTrento
whose page_id is `261655927236608`. I'm not the admin of the page, so I don't have any admin token.

I'd like to get the app_id of the page_id but the following query:

```
Select app_id from page where page_id ="261655927236608"
```

returns the following app_id:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "app_id": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

CBroe, I'm basing my assumptions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541368/facebook-reviews-tab-data-where-is-it-stored-in-graph-api-and-how-to-access/5880705#5880705) question. Even if a page is not falling in the "Application" category, it could host an app for rating the service, at least according to the answerer. The specs for `review` don't state if a non-Application page can be coupled to an application.

I mean, I want to get data from this tab:
[image]

Comment: That is not an app page, but one in the category "College & University". So I can’t see what makes you think that it would “have” an app id?

Comment: Looking at https://www.facebook.com/help/271128916342286, it looks to me as if those kind of reviews for a page are a standard Facebook feature, and nothing that would have anything to do with _custom_ apps.

Comment: OK, looks like the app id mentioned in the other question (6261817190) is the id of the official Facebook review app – but filtering the `review` table with that as `reviewee_id` seems to get all kinds of reviews made lately, not restricted to any certain page.

Comment: By filtering you mean calling http://graph.facebook.com/6261817190/reviews?reviewee_id=261655927236608?

Comment: No, I’m talking about the FQL tables.

Comment: Ok,could you post the query you used? With SELECT rating FROM review WHERE reviewee_id = 261655927236608 i get an empty array (not all reviews as in your case).

Comment: `reviewee_id` is the app, not the page.

Comment: so basically the answer to my question is: you can't grab the reviews for a particular page. 
Correct?