# Facebook reviews ( Most recent ) Using Facebook graph API and Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get access to the data that appears under the reviews tab in the Facebook Page https://www.facebook.com/HRCMallOfAmerica/reviews (Specifically Most recent).

```
import json
import oauth2
import urllib
import urllib2
import psycopg2


url_params = {}
url_params['client_id'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
url_params['client_secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
url_params['grant_type'] = 'client_credentials'
host = 'graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'
encoded_params = urllib.urlencode(url_params)
url = 'https://%s?%s'%(host,encoded_params)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    access_token = response.read().split('access_token')[1][1:]
except:
    print "Unable to get / parse the URL %s"%(url)
print 'ACCESS_TOKEN %s'%(access_token)
```

I can get their own feed by using the below url

```
url=https://graph.facebook.com/HRCMallOfAmerica/feed?access_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

while seeing the answer from the below question.

[Facebook "Reviews" Tab Data -- Where is it stored in Graph API and how to access it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541368/facebook-reviews-tab-data-where-is-it-stored-in-graph-api-and-how-to-access)

I have call the urls called

`http://graph.facebook.com/622086227888427/reviews`

```
http://graph.facebook.com/622086227888427/reviews?limit=100000000&offset=0
```

But both urls throws same error like

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `reviews` edge for pages – [`ratings`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings) is the correct one to use.

Comment: Am not a admin of that page.

Comment: And am having one page so I have admin access the review in that page was shown by using the below url https://graph.facebook.com/458709147600298/ratings?access_token=CAAFL3br74PYBAPz2Wct95Uipg5y2OvQim3zyH8QojlMkYT6ZAlorVWDifWiTbWJ4abb4cgXpKqM2fP64ZBjC1u8j685l8zZAbETiGsHOSF3NXC8AreffA9r9vKBEs4cwWfNkNJKFAkVO88yXwlub04ZBLiM4pkI0PJhLj0yvMrHsuBRQLg0bG6OC5mVUTzi9Vi2iZCQoUOgZDZD Like that i want to get for others

Comment: the above is page access token which I was got in fb developer page ( me/accounts)

Comment: As you can see from the documentation page I linked to, this needs a page access token. Or in other words: Ratings for pages that you don’t admin are not available to you via API.

Comment: Oh, then how we can get the reivew of others page ( which am not admin ). Or else we have request for permission to access that

Comment: What part of _“Ratings for pages that you don’t admin are not available to you via API”_ is unclear?

Comment: Am don't have a admin access for this (https://www.facebook.com/HRCMallOfAmerica/reviews) page. Then I that possible to get the reviews data

Comment: Is any other ways to access those pages.

Comment: **Not possible.** Is that finally clear enough for you now?

Comment: Yes, last one Is that possible to request them to provide their page access token to get those data

Comment: Of course you can get that data if you can get an admin for that page to provide you with a page access token … but you won’t get a list of page admins without a page access token either, so you would need to find a different way to ask them for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the admin of this page, you can get it with graph API in the 'rating' node (more info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/):

```
GET /v2.5/{page-id}?fields=ratings HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

you can do this with python, using facebook-sdk.

If you are not the admin of that page, you can't get that information using graph API.

Comment: If you aren't the admin of this page, you can get it by passing the Page ID to a 3rd party API such as https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/demo/facebook/